# Where do I find the REST urls and json structs corresponding to each vmc command?

Tags: rest, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use CloudFOundry REST calls to create app, bind service etc instead of using vmc or eclipse plugin. I know we can use vcap-java-client for this but I also wanted to test calling the REST services directly such as by using cUrl utility. Where do I find the REST urls and json structs corresponding to each vmc command ?

Answer (score 3):

The best way for you to see the actual rest calls to the Cloud Controller is executing the vmc commands and add the -t. So for example:

```
vmc apps -t
```

So this vmc command will show you a list of your apps and so what you get out of the additional -t is a more verbose information which shows the Cloud Controller service you are calling. In this case it would be /apps

The same command on the bottom will give you the exact output you would get from the above vmc command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: <Your-Oauth-token>" https://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps
```

The Authorization token can also be found in the -t generated output. you need to copy the entire Authorization "bearer"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have done vmc apps -t, but I did not find anything called Authorization "bearer" in the output. Can you please tell me how to get this bearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Sudipta,

When you login and run vmc apps -t, you should see the following output:

```
Getting applications.  >>>
REQUEST: GET /apps
REQUEST_HEADERS:
  accept : application/json
  user-agent : Ruby
  authorization : bearer <token>
content-length : 0
```

The **authorization** in REQUEST_HEADERS is what you would need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to run commands like -
curl -H "Authorization: <Your-Oauth-token>" https://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps
curl -H "Authorization: <Your-Oauth-token>" https://api.cloudfoundry.com/services

but what about the commands specific to a particular application / service ? What should be the curl commands alternative to the commands like 'vmc app [app_name]', bind-service [INSTANCE] [APP], service [service_name] etc?

Comment: And I am little bit confused about one more thing. I was looking into CloudControllerClientV2.java file to get the details about REST Urls. But the URLs are not matching with what it supposed to be. 
e.g. as per the getApplications() method the REST url to get all the applications should be something like - 
/apps?inline-relations-depth=2

but curl command with the url https://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps is giving the actual result. Why there is inconsistency between these two ?

Comment: Could someone help please by providing the answer to the question I asked on Jan 16 ?

Comment: Hey Sudipta, The vcap-java-client does the same REST calls as you and I are doing using curl. If you look at the getApplications() method inside CloudControllerClientV2, you'll see that it is doing the same REST call "urlPath = urlPath + "/apps" as if we are doing "api.cloudfoundry.com/apps"

Comment: Regarding your comment on how to use the REST calls for a particular application, Just do a vmc bind-service -t and you will get a verbose output which will show you the REST call that you need to use in order to do the bind-service for your particular application.